# How to check with an array have some values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic

How to verify with i have only 2 or 3 numbers inside this?
without this ----> if(Array.includes(1) && !Array.includes(3))

```
const servicesTest: IServices[] = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Hair',
    price: 25,
    icon: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/7478/7478480.png'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Beard',
    price: 20,
    icon: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/7578/7578754.png'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Eyebrow',
    price: 15,
    icon: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2821/2821012.png'
  }
]
```

if the client choose hair + beard this will be 40 not 45.
I´m doing this:

```js
 const name = findServices.map(services => services.name)
    if (name.includes('Hair') && name.includes('Beard') && !name.includes('Eyebrown')) {
      return (
        setTotalDay(prevState => prevState + 40),
        setTotalMonth(prevState => prevState + 40)
      )
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to check if the array has only two distinct value?

Comment: @Mureinik, can be too, because with i have 10 values i will need to reject 8 values inside the condition of the IF

Comment: "A giant IF"?!  start with a working flow, then work to make it as efficient as possible. you may find that performance of an if statement is really not worth considering.

Comment: could you provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example maybe you can provide more of your code. some example of what your solution looks like. some samples of 'starting with' and 'this is what I want".

Comment: this is working ==> if(array.includes(1) && includes(2) && !includes(3), 4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8) this is a big condition, there is a way with less code?

Comment: @user308839 so what's the expected output? `false`? `[1,2]`?

Comment: I did again @Mureinik

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array of discounts like this:

```
const discounts = [{
  price: 30,
  ids: [1, 2],
}];
```

Then check if the array has only discounted items like this:

```
array.length === discount.ids.length && array.every((item) => discount.ids.includes(item.id))
```

```js
const discounts = [{
  price: 30,
  ids: [1, 2],
}];

const discounted = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Hair',
    price: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Beard',
    price: 30,
  },
];

const fullPrice = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Hair',
    price: 20,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Beard',
    price: 30,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Tea',
    price: 30,
  },
];

console.log("discounted", getTotal(discounted));
console.log("full price", getTotal(fullPrice));

function getTotal(array) {
  for (const discount of discounts) {
    if (
      array.length === discount.ids.length &&
      array.every((item) => discount.ids.includes(item.id))
    ) {
      return discount.price;
    }
  }
  return array.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.price, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

answering your question before the edit.

Assuming we have this array

`const Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];`

Let's say we want to check if values 2 and 3 exist.

We store the values in an array `let toCheck = [2,3]`;

We can use function `every` to loop all the elements of toCheck array against the `Array` const

Example Follows:

```
const Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let toCheck = [1,2];
const allExist = toCheck.every(value => {
  return Array.includes(value);
});
```

Hope it helps.